# how HDFS will divide the file in block

Tags: hdfs

i know that hdfs divide file in 128 mb block

now suppose a file size of 1034mb is been divided in 128*8 blocks.what will happen 10 mb will it be allocated the whole 128 mb or just 10mb block.

if yes. then rest 118mb gets wasted.
how this issue can be resolved.

I have just started learning hadoop.

please pardon me if my question is naive.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large Block Size in HDFS! How is the unused space accounted for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012924/large-block-size-in-hdfs-how-is-the-unused-space-accounted-for)

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012924/large-block-size-in-hdfs-how-is-the-unused-space-accounted-for